# SET IDENTITY_INSERT [project] ON; does not work

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am importing data from Table X to Table Y, so I am programming the script, so I want the identity for the `ID` column in Table Y turned off, then I import the data and then turn it back on.

I did as following

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [project] ON;
// Script for inserting Data Comes here
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [project] OFF;
```

but I get this error message

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'project' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

What I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't see a column list in your `INSERT` (not that `Insert Data From Table X to Table Y` is remotely valid anyway)

Comment: People normally miss the `and`: "a column list is used **and** IDENTITY_INSERT is ON"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the columns like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableY  ON
Insert Into TableY (Id, Column1, Column2) Select Id, Column1, Column2 FROM TableX
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableY  OFF
```

Comment: //that was not my point, that part i Enter the script

Comment: the insert part doesn't have any problem, it is a script which could work fine if manually set the identity ID Field to No , SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableY  ON is problem

Comment: how you have decided it that SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableY ON is problem ??

Comment: @nnmmss - You're wrong. That error is thrown by the `INSERT` not the `SET`

Comment: @nnmmss And just how do you know SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableY ON is the  problem.  Post your script.  Really if you run just that line you get the posted error?

Comment: Check that you are setting the IDENTITY_INSERT to the insert target table, not the source table (project)?

Comment: I got to the table and set Identity of Id Field to No, and run the insert, it works, but if the identity of Id Field is Yes, with SET IDENTITY_INSERT i can not insert any thing

Comment: **Post your INSERT statement**

Comment: SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.project On;
insert into dbo.project
select 
 [PrjSubcode]
      ,[Prjcode]
      ,[SubCode]
      ,[DisLimMin]
      ,[DisLimMax]
      ,[CableLen]
      ,[GTag]
      ,[EndStr]
      ,[NTag]
      ,[FTag]      
      ,[CDwgNum]
      ,[TDwgNum]
      ,[Line1]
      ,[Line2]
      ,dbo.Trans_ChangeRevision(CableRev)
      ,dbo.Trans_ChangeRevision(TermRev)
      ,dbo.Trans_ChangeRevision(SubRev)
      ,[KKS]
      ,null,null,null,null,null,null,null
     
  FROM [sql].[CableTest].[dbo].[tblproject]
  where [PrjSubcode]=290
  
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.project OFF;

Comment: Add the columns you want to insert those values and the id column too. Like so "Insert Into dbo.Project (*id column here*, *other columns here*) select (*id column here*, *other columns here*) from..."

Comment: the insert Statement works fine if i go to management Studio and design the Table Project and set the Identity attribute to No. do i think it is not about the insert statement

Comment: If your insert works with the identity set to No, then you obviously have Nullable identity column definition, because you are not inserting values to that column. IF you have the identity set to Yes then you need to specify and insert the value when inserting rows with IDENTITY_INSERT on. Please, go read from MSDN, nothing more we can say to you.